# How to delete files from a directory using apache camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am new to Camel and was exploring ways to delete files from a particular directory using Camel. I wanted to know about the different ways of deleting files from a directory based on filters like deleting all .txt files or deleting the files which were not modified within 20 days etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not the purpose of Camel to delete files.

You can more easily use Java File API for that. And there is also bash scripts for such use-cases, eg housecleaning.

But if you want to attempt Camel then the file component can be used as a consumer to consume files from a filter filtered by name pattern, and also you can file by file modification day and therefore compare for age > 20 days etc.

Then you can route to a log null endpoint

Something ala

```
from file ? xxxxx
    to log dummy ? log = OFF
```

But as sad, then just use Java File API code is likely better.